# Problem moving windows to other workspaces (ubuntu 13.10)

Tags: unity, 13.10, compiz, shortcut-keys, workspaces

Ok, so I had ubuntu 13.04 and I could normaly move windows to other workspaces pressing "ctrl+alt+shift+any arrow button". But I recently upgraded to 13.10 and now, when I press those buttons, I only can move the window to the workspaces at the sides but not the ones below it (for example: if I have a window in the top left workspace, I can move it to the one on the top right and then get it back to the top left workspace, but I can't move it to the bottom left or the bottom right workspace) and to do that I have to click the workspaces icon (the one that shows all the workspaces) and manually drag the window to the workspace I want, and that is quite slow and annoying. Is there any way to fix that?

Thanks.

Comment: Keyboard settings > Shortcuts - changing a few of those may help...

Comment: How come I didn't think for of that, seems like they changed the command in 13.10 to super+alt+shift+re pag/av pag. I changed it again to the other command.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the 'Navigation' bit I think you need.
[image]